# Python PILLOW library uses CPU for Image Processing, can it be done on GPU?

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I made a small Python 3.x app for myself that resizes all the images from a folder by a certain given percentage.

The app suports multicore CPU, as in it splits the work done on as many threads as the CPU has.

The bottleneck here is the CPU, as my RAM memory remains 40% free and my HDD usage is 3% during runtime, but all CPU cores are near 100%.

Is there a way to process the images on the GPU? I think it would greatly improve performance as GPU have more than 4 cores.

Here is a bit of code on how the processing is done:

```
def worker1(file_list, percentage, thread_no):
    """thread class"""
    global counter
    save_dir = askdir_entry.get() + '/ResizeImage/'
    for picture in file_list:
        image = Image.open(picture, mode='r')
        image_copy = image.copy()
        (width, height) = image.size
        filename = os.path.split(picture)[1]
        image_copy.thumbnail((width * (int(percentage) / 100), height * (int(percentage) / 100)))
        info_area.insert('end', '\n' + filename)
        info_area.see(tkinter.END)
        image_copy.save(save_dir + filename)
        counter += 1
        if counter % 3 == 0:
            update_counter(1, thread_no)
    update_counter(0, thread_no)


def resize():
    global start_time
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    percentage = percentage_textbox.get()
    if not percentage:
        info_area.insert('end', 'Please write a percentage!')
        return
    askdir_entry.config(state='disabled')
    percentage_textbox.config(state='disabled')
    file_list = glob.glob(askdir_entry.get() + '/*.jp*g')
    info_area.insert('end', 'Found ' + str(len(file_list)) + ' pictures.\n')
    cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    info_area.insert('end', 'Number of threads: ' + str(cpu))
    info_area.insert('end', '\nResizing pictures..\n\n')
    if not os.path.exists(askdir_entry.get() + '/ResizeImage'):
        os.makedirs(askdir_entry.get() + '/ResizeImage')
    counter_label.config(text='-')
    for i in range(0, cpu):
        file_list_chunk = file_list[int(i * len(file_list) / cpu):int((i + 1) * len(file_list) / cpu)]
        threading.Thread(target=worker1, args=(file_list_chunk, percentage, i + 1)).start()
```

Comment: I'd have thought calling tkinter functions from another thread was a no no. I'd also suggest that the global interpreter lock may stifle any benefits you hope to get from multiple threads, go with processes! I don't think Pillow supports gpu but maybe numpy/scipy could [work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086621/how-to-reduce-an-image-size-in-image-processing-scipy-numpy-python).

Comment: Well I did get a 50% improvement when using multiple threads, even though theoretically I should have gotten a 200% improvement for my 4 core CPU. Yet on a single thread, only 1 CPU core was working, while now all 4 are nearing 100%, which might suggest multi-threading works(?). Thanks for the opinion.

Comment: Many ImageMagick commands can use GPU via OpenCL (including resizing --- see https://www.imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php) or CPU with multithreading via OpenMP (see https://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#threads). Also OpenCV (Python or C++) can use GPU.

Answer (score 19):

Image resize is not actually very CPU-intensive. You'll find that a lot of your overall time is being spent in the image decode and encode libraries where a GPU is of little help.

A simple thing would be to try swapping PIL out for [pillow-simd](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd). It's compatible with pillow, but many inner loops have been replaced with hand-written vector code. You can typically expect [a 6x to 10x speedup for the image resizing step](https://python-pillow.org/pillow-perf/).

libjpeg supports very fast shrink on load. It can do a x2, x4 or x8 shrink as part of image decode -- you can easily get a 20x speedup for large shrinks. You'd need to look into how to enable this in pillow.

You could also consider other image processing libraries. [libvips](http://libvips.github.io/libvips/) has a fast and low memory command-line tool for image shrinking, [`vipsthumbnail`](http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html). Combined with [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), you can easily get a huge speedup.

For example, I can make a directory of 1,000 large JPG images:

```
$ vipsheader ../nina.jpg 
../nina.jpg: 6048x4032 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
$ for i in {1..1000}; do cp ../nina.jpg $i.jpg; done
```

Then shrink with imagemagick like this:

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do convert $i.jpg -resize 128x128 tn_$i.jpg; done
real    6m43.627s
user    31m29.894s
sys 1m51.352s
```

Or with GNU `parallel` and `vipsthumbnail` like this:

```
$ time parallel vipsthumbnail -s 128 ::: *.jpg
real    0m11.940s
user    1m15.820s
sys 0m11.916s
```

About 33x faster.

You could use `convert` with `parallel`, but each `convert` process needs about 400mb of ram with a 6k x 4k JPG image, so it would be easy to fill memory. You'd probably need to tune it a bit. `vipsthumbnail` only needs a few mb of ram, so you can safely run many instances at once.